# C#-Implementation of an iterative algorithm for the derivation of an n-fold concatenation of a function f

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

I am currently trying to implement an iterative algorithm in C# for an optimization problem, but I am currently stuck on.

I have n blackboxes, each of which expects an input x and outputs [image]. Each blackbox is also parameterized with constants that are individual to each blackbox, but are constant.

The blackboxes are now connected in series, i.e., the output of [image] (we call it [image] is the input of [image], the output of [image] is in turn the input of [image] and so on until [image].

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image] and [image] are constants, but they are individual per blackbox.

Mathematically, I would now have defined this as having an n-fold concatenation of the function [image]

[image]

Now I am searching for the input [image] of the [image], which has the property that the difference [image] between the input of the first blackbox and the output of the last blackbox is maximal.

[image]

Mathematically seen the extreme points of the difference function are looked for, i.e. the zeros of their 1st derivative.

[image]

I am now stuck that I need to implement an algorithm that is best iterative and also works with arbitrary number of n blackboxes. In plain english: what is the best input x0 for the first blackbox so that the output of the last blackbox is maximal.

Who can help me? Pseudo-code is sufficient to get an approach.

Comment: Did you try to come up with a solution for x after first-order differentiation? I know it isn't easy, maybe you can use some solvers (Wolfram solver?) to get a solution for x and then you just have to implement it. The problem is very interesting though :-)

Comment: Good ol' Wikipedia shows you how to calculate the derivative of a function like this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule Finding a global maximum though could be difficult. You could maybe use Newton's Method to find the zero of the derivative for a local maximum, but you'd have to differentiate again. Rather you than me... :)

Comment: I think that isn't really a programming- or software problem but rather one belonging to the realm of (numerical) mathematics.

Comment: Questions about implementation issues with software algorithms in a specific programming language (even if it's a highly mathematical algorithm) are entirely on-topic here. Even if only 0.0001% of users will understand what's going on in the question. However, question of the "I don't know how to finalize this algorithm before I start implementing" kind do not belong here, and should be asked over on https://math.stackexchange.com, especially if pseudocode is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

For a single-variable unconstrained continuous optimization problem, you could use a [line search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search) method like [golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search). The iterative search starts with a wide search range. The range is narrowed down until the desired accuracy is reached.
The method may converge to a local maximum. It does not require derivatives.

There are implicit constraints in your problem. The denominators in the blackbox functions probably should stay unequal to zero.

Alternative methods for [univariate optimization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uni-variate-optimization-vs-multivariate-optimization/) include:

1. [Fibonacci search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fibonacci-search/)
2. [Polynomial interpolation](https://youtu.be/kOumkn7Mcb8)
3. Safeguarded polynomial interpolation

To get an overview, you could plot the function by connecting sampled function values with lines.

The choice of the method depends on the cost of function evaluation. If it is expensive to get function values, it makes sense to use interpolation.